# About Memory Address convention?

Tags: c, memory

When we are representing the Memory address as 0x0 or 0xFFFFFFF0 what does it means.It's convention or have any specific meaning?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean? It is not clear what you're asking. Do you know hexadecimal notation?

Comment: 0 = 0x0. 2^32 - 1 = 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: @someuser It's not super-clear to use `^` as the exponentiation operator in the C context (where it's bitwise XOR, of course).

Comment: Ok. `pow(2, 32) - 1;` (but we catch overflow there :( ).

Comment: Now i get it thanks but what 0x0 represent any starting memory address,means like we start counting from 0 so what computer starts reading from memory address 0x0.